# Is there a way to set maxAllowedContentLength/maxRequestLength per Controller in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have several controllers that handle file uploads and require large timeouts and files.
On the other hand I have several controllers that should execute in a more timely fashion, and would like to take advantage of the security provided by lower maxRequestLength's and executionTimeout's.

I would like to have certain web api controllers or actions be able to set maxAllowedContentLength/maxRequestLength/executionTimeout so that each action or controller can specify it's own requirements.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could break apart the controllers into separate service endpoints all hosted under the same site, but using separate configuration for each.

Comment: I'm planning on deploying to Azure WebRole, or AWS Elastic Beanstalk both of which typically allow one deployed site.  Is this possible within a single site/deployment item?  Is this possible by putting a controller in a separate directory with it's own web.config?

Comment: According to the docs, you should be able to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx

Comment: @Kwal, how? Please provide a more detailed answer, or at least a link so that users can follow. Because we also have such a requirement, and while your answer is a hope, it's not more than a clue to us. Thank you.