# How to increase maxRequestLength per Controller in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web-config, maxrequestlength

I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945817/is-there-a-way-to-set-maxallowedcontentlength-maxrequestlength-per-controller-in) since 2012, but I want to launch again the question.

Is it possible to increase the maxRequestLength per service or controller instead of changing the Web.Config?

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240"/>
</system.web>
```

If it can't be programmatically, can be done in the Web.Config but it can be focused only for some Controllers?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825849/mvc3-action-file-size-limit) question